# Demandware - how to use jQuery in <isscript>

Tags: jquery, demandware

Hey folks I need to store information about 2 checkboxes.
I need the state if they had been clicked or not.

But I need to put that information into pdict, because I need it on another site.

So I already have a click() function in jQuery but I need that result to be put into pdict.

Background:
You are on a site and can enable/disable 2 checkboxes.
But then you have to log-in into that site, using a totally different Pipeline.
If the login was successful, I need that checkbox-states back in the original Pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible without refreshing the page in some way.
Because jQuery is a client-side and dscript is server side, the only way they can communicate is if you pass the variable back to the server.

In jQuery you can pass the variable back into the URL with a variable and call it back on the server side with a pdict.HttpParameterMap.etc... and set it as a session variable/Pipeline Variable that is called on the redirect at which point you can gather this information.